# "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values"

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-integration

[Problem Details and clues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD1tW.png)

```
%For this problem write a script file called NC.m that implements 
%the Newton-Cotes method of integration for an arbitrary function f(x). It
%should take as inputs the function and the limits of integration [a: b] and
%output the value of the definite integral. Specifically, you should use the
%Trapezoid rule as presented in Equation (11.73)
function [f]= NC(a,b,fun) %newton-cotes 
%a and b are limits of intergration 
%setting it up 
f(a)= fun(a); %y value for lower limit 
f(b)= fun(b); %y value for upper limit 
%the actual function 
f= (b-a)*(f(a)+f(b))/2; 
end
```

What am i doing wrong? When I type, [f]= NC(-3,0,fun) and set fun=  @(x)normpdf(x) . it keeps on returning "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values". Can someone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you try to assign to `f(a)` where `a=0`, so you mixed between a vector index and value, as well as use `f` for two different purposes, one as the output of the function NC, and one for the value of fun(x), that's not a good idea.

Instead you can define the output in a separate variable:

```
fa=fun(a);
fb=fun(n); 
f=(b-a)*(fa+fb)/2;
```

or just write: `f=(b-a)*(fun(a)+fun(b))/2;`

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the assignments to `f(a)` and `f(b)`.

The syntax `f(x)` has three interpretations in MATLAB that are dependent on the type of `f`:

1. indexing the array `f` using the strictly positive integer index (or logical index) `x`
2. evaluation of the function handle `f` using the value of the variable `x`
3. manipulation, in some manner, of the symbolic function`f(x)` using the symbolic variable `x`.

Due to MATLAB's dynamic typing and defaulting to double arrays, MATLAB is interpreting the assignments to `f(a)` and `f(b)` as the item (1): MATLAB is taking `f` to be a double array and is expecting `a` and `b` to be valid indexes into the array.

Per your intent then, a simple assignment to variable symbols without the parentheses (e.g., `fa` and `fb`) should solve your problem.